# Как определить, что книга Excel является вставленной в презентацию PowerPoint?

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, vsto

В PowerPoint можно вставить таблицу Excel. Когда пользователь редактирует эту таблицу, то он работает с ней в полноценном Excel. Т.е. в этот момент подгружаются все add-in-ы и соответственно отрабатываются все сообщения.

Как через api Excel определить, что открытая книга (Workbook) является встроенной (embedded)?